# User unable to login with new account

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-registration

I am new to Django and was creating a simple user registration page.

I am able to create new users from my register.html page. I can see the users are created in  Django's built-in administration page. However when I try to login into my website with the newly created user, I am redirected to the error page.

```
def newuser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=email, email=email)
        if created:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/master/messages')
    else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/master/invalid')
```

It seems that the password is not getting saved in hashed format. When I reset the password from the admin page, I can login with the new password.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What error do you get on the error page? And ooh, I do not know if its a great idea rolling out your own authentication instead of using something like Django all-auth. It does basic stuffs like what you're trying to accomplish, and can go the extra mile with tons of additions too. If you're considering production, perhaps you might wanna give all-auth a try

Comment: I am able to create the account but when I try to login with the credentials that I created during registration, it redirects me to the incorrect password page. The login code looks like this -     `def auth_view(request):
 username = request.POST.get('email','')
 password = request.POST.get('password','')
 user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

 if user is not None:
  auth.login(request, user)
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
 else:
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')`